# Rename file while uploading?

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I have the following code in my Wordpress. I need to add every uploaded image a counting number like, image_1, image_2, image_3 and so on..

The purpose of this is that every uploaded image attached to post, gets post ID name, and counting number in end to it.

It would be great if some one help me with this. Thanks!

```
<?php

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse_25894_handle_upload_prefilter');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'wpse_25894_handle_upload');

function wpse_25894_handle_upload_prefilter( $file )
{
add_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse_25894_custom_upload_dir');
return $file;
}

function wpse_25894_handle_upload( $fileinfo )
{
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse_25894_custom_upload_dir');
return $fileinfo;
}

function wpse_25894_custom_upload_dir($path)
{   
/*
 * Determines if uploading from inside a post/page/cpt - if not, default Upload folder is used
 */
$use_default_dir = ( isset($_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && $_REQUEST['post_id'] == 0 ) ?   true : false; 
if( !empty( $path['error'] ) || $use_default_dir )
    return $path; //error or uploading not from a post/page/cpt 

/*
 * Save uploads in ID based folders 
 *
 */

 $customdir = '/' . $_REQUEST['post_id'];


$path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); //remove default subdir (year/month)
$path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);      
$path['subdir']  = $customdir;
$path['path']   .= $customdir; 
$path['url']    .= $customdir;  

return $path;
}
// The filter runs when resizing an image to make a thumbnail or intermediate size.
add_filter( 'image_make_intermediate_size', 'wpse_123240_rename_intermediates' );

function wpse_123240_rename_intermediates( $image ) {

// Split the $image path into directory/extension/name
$info = pathinfo($image);
$dir = $info['dirname'] . '/';
$ext = '.' . $info['extension'];
$name = wp_basename( $image, "$ext" );

// Get image information 
// Image edtor is used for this
$img = wp_get_image_editor( $image );

// Build our new image name
$postid = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
$random = rand(1,5);

$new_name = $dir . $postid . '_' . $random . $ext;

// Rename the intermediate size
$did_it = rename( $image, $new_name );

// Renaming successful, return new name
if( $did_it )
return $new_name;
return $image;
}
?>
```

Now this code generates images named postid_randomnumber.jpg

I just need to add 20 images at maximum, so if I can have numbers from 1-20, that is also working fine with my purposes.

-- UPDATE --

I canged the last part of code to this, it is not maybe the cleanest solution, but it works:

```
function wpse_123240_rename_intermediates( $image ) 

{
// Split the $image path into directory/extension/name
$info = pathinfo($image);
$dir = $info['dirname'] . '/';
$ext = '.' . $info['extension'];
$name = wp_basename( $image, "$ext" );

// Get image information 
// Image edtor is used for this
$img = wp_get_image_editor( $image );

//$count = get_option( 'wpa59168_counter', 1 );

// Build our new image name
$postid = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
$increment = 1;

$new_name = $dir . $postid . '_1' . $ext;

while(is_file($new_name)) {
 $increment++;
 $new_name = $dir . $postid . '_' . $increment . $ext;
}

// Rename the intermediate size
$did_it = rename( $image, $new_name );

// Renaming successful, return new name
if( $did_it )
    return $new_name;

return $image;

}
```

Comment: With above code you have posted you are not able to achieve renamed of a file ?

Comment: It works fine with one file and the file is renamed with post ID, but when I upload several images it does not work. It uploads all original images, but just creates one image from those.

Comment: Above code is for renaming the file only. You have not posted the code which handle upload and calling above function to rename the files. Can you please post that code also ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, and now it is the full code.

Comment: Your filter "image_make_intermediate_size" runs whenever there is resizing the image is there right ? At a time you will have only one image to be resize in your filter, can you please confirm. If its being applied to one image which all other images you want to differentiate ?

Comment: Hey, yes it runs always when I add images to post.

I tested and added 5 images with "rand(1,10)" and it saves the original and generates additional 5 images with random numbers, so it is working and it is looping that ok.

I usually add 5-15 images, so I like to have running number like this:
postid_1.jpg
postid_2.jpg
postid_3.jpg
and so on..

Comment: Can you please post the updated code ? I guess you will require to use for loop instead of rand() as rand might give you duplicate in case your range is too small.

Comment: Yes, I also think that maybe some for loop with $i or something like that, but I don't know how to implement it. The whole code is in the first message.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can we get total number of images before calling the rand() function than I can provide you example of for loop

Comment: That is good question, I don't know where it gets the total numbers of images. All the code is above, I edit the code and put that random thing in there so you will see the whole code.

Comment: As per the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_make_intermediate_size at a time it will only have one file. I am not expert on wordpress but I can advise if you can use global variable for the count and put it at the end of image as image name. But I am not sure where you can declare it and how it would be available in your function considering it is word press filter.

Comment: I get it to work, see update. Not maybe the cleanest solution, but it is working like it should.

Comment: Not sure if this will work because at a moment you have one file in the function. You need to have global variable to hold the increment number.

Comment: I have tested it with several files and it works ok. If you have any suggestions to do this better, I will test and update.

Comment: As i dont have much knowledge on wordpress I am not sure but if its working for you than great, glad to hear that. :)